# swift CoreData predicates to filter all the child data of a given parent

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

There are two entities `Child` and `Parent`. `Parent` and `Child` is one to many relationship, one `Parent` with many `Child`.

The code I referred to is as following and it can filter all the data of `Child` level whose Attribute `text` contains `yes`:

```
@State private var predicate: NSPredicate? = NSPredicate(format: "text contains[c] %@", "yes")
@ObservedObject private var db = CoreDataDB<Child>()

for child in self.db.loadDB(predicate: self.predicate):
    ....
```

What I want to do is to get all the `Child` level's data belong to current `Child` data's `Parent`.

```
var child: Child

// How to write this line???
@State private var predicate: NSPredicate? = NSPredicate(format: "parent = %@", "self.child.parent")

@ObservedObject private var db = CoreDataDB<Child>()

for child in self.db.loadDB(predicate: self.predicate):
    ....
```

I do not know how to write the `predicate` above to filter data that belong to the same `Parent` with current `child` in current `child`'s View.

`NSPredicate(format: "parent = %@", "self.child.parent")` will get nothing when `for child in self.db.loadDB(predicate: self.predicate):`.

`NSPredicate(format: "child.parent = %@", "self.child.parent")` will get error saying `keypath child.parent not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Child id=1> with userInfo of (null)`

What I need to say is that `text` of `Child Entity` in the code is an Attribute I created, but `parent` of `Child Entity` is auto created by the `one to many` relationship with `Parent Entity`. I cannot see `parent` Attribute in `xcdataModelId` file but I can use it in the code.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
NSPredicate(format: "parent = %@", "self.child.parent")
```

you substitute a *string* for the `%@` placeholder. What you want is

```
NSPredicate(format: "parent = %@", self.child.parent)
```

which searches for all entities whose `parent` is equal to the `parent` of `self.child`.